# How to enable stiffness using C++

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to enable/disable the stiffness using C++ API. But I don't know how to instantiate a service variable.
I am not sure about what should I put between "<>". The code is attached bellow. Anyone can help me?

```
  ros::init(argc, argv, "controller");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher controller_pub = n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1000);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  int count = 0;

  ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<??>("/body_stiffness/enable");
  while (ros::ok())
  {
      geometry_msgs::Twist control;
      control.linear.x = 1;
      control.linear.y = 0;
      control.angular.z = 0;
      controller_pub.publish(control);  
      ros::spinOnce();

      loop_rate.sleep();
      ++count;
  }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135071/how-to-enable-stiffness-using-c++/) by [borghetti](https://answers.ros.org/users/12471/borghetti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [nao_driver wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/nao_driver?distro=fuerte#Services-1), it's an empty service, so you would use `std_srvs::Empty`:

```
ros::ServiceClient client = n.serviceClient<std_srvs::Empty>("/body_stiffness/enable");
```

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2